# Quickest sorting mechanism for sorting by multiple predicates in python

Tags: python, performance, sorting

```
import operator
a = [[1,0.7,1],[4,0.8,1],[5,0.8,0.99],[11,0.9,0.98]]
b = sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True);
c = sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True);
s = sorted(a, key=lambda x : (x[2],x[1]), reverse=True);
i = sorted(a, key = operator.itemgetter(2, 1),reverse=True);
```

out of following outputs such as c,s and i which is the quickest method (in terms of time in worst case) for sorting a 5 Diamensional array of length around 20,000. Or are there any specific way of doing it rather than c,s,i

Comment: Use the `timeit` module and see which one runs the fastest for you

Comment: Method 1 and 2 are different from the rest.

Comment: The time complexity is exactly the same for all of these - they are using the same sorting algorithm, and your `key` function doesn't do anything crazy. So, this is an empirical question, one which you have all the tools at your disposal to elucidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure there's any sense comparing the first two with the 3rd and 4th - they do different things.

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

Sorts the list of lists by the second element *only*, while...

```
sorted(b, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=True)
```

Sorts the list of lists by the third element *only*, regardless of how the list was sorted before.

---

```
sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x[2],x[1]), reverse=True)
sorted(a, key=operator.itemgetter(2, 1), reverse=True)
```

Both of these methods sort the list by the third *as well as* the second element. Ties on the 3rd element are broken by the second, basically.

---

**Performance**

### Small

```
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.62 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.9 µs per loop
```

The last method is faster simply because `lambda` functions are slower.

### Medium (*100K elements*)

```
10 loops, best of 3: 60.7 ms per loop
10 loops, best of 3: 50.7 ms per loop
```

### Large (*3M elements*)

```
1 loop, best of 3: 2.07 s per loop
1 loop, best of 3: 1.71 s per loop
```

It is important to understand that the theoretical time complexity of these methods are *exactly* the same - their order of growth is identical. The only difference here is the techniques you use, which can make minor differences in speed. It is also important to understand that if you're looking for high performance, Python isn't the language you should be working with.

Comment: Yes, I suspect these differences to disappear as the list grows larger, and the overhead of mapping the key function gets dwarfed by the sorting.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Added some more numbers.

Comment: @COLDSPEED. Python sort is stable. Sorting by the secondary key first and then by the primary key makes sense.

Comment: @COOLSPEED I am doing an Machine Learning project, and I prefer to use python for it, are there any language that are capable of doing these kind of calculation easily except R and Matlab.( I have some issues and draw backs in implementing those for my project

Comment: @AmutheezanSivagnanam there is a module called "timeit" that you could look into.